# How do I fix a runtime error for a mail merge?

Tags: runtime, mailmerge

I am using the macro below to save individual word docs and pdfs from a mail merge. The macro runs and saves both files for the first letter, but then I get this error and I can't figure out how to fix it.

Macro:
Sub MailMergeToPdfBasic()                                                        ' Mark the start of the Subroutine (i.e. Macro) and name it "MailMergeToPdf"
' Macro created by Imnoss Ltd
' Please share freely while retaining attribution
' Last Updated 2021-05-03
Dim masterDoc As Document, singleDoc As Document, lastRecordNum As Long   ' Create variables ("Post-it Notes") for later use
Set masterDoc = ActiveDocument                                               ' Identify the ActiveDocument (foremost doc when Macro run) as "masterDoc"

```
masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdLastRecord                   ' jump to the last active record (active = ticked in edit recipients)
lastRecordNum = masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord                  ' retrieve the record number of the last active record so we know when to stop

masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdFirstRecord                  ' jump to the first active record (active = ticked in edit recipients)
Do While lastRecordNum > 0                                                   ' create a loop, lastRecordNum is used to end the loop by setting to zero (see below)
    masterDoc.MailMerge.Destination = wdSendToNewDocument                    ' Identify that we are creating a word docx (and no e.g. an email)
    masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.FirstRecord = masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord              ' Limit the selection to just one document by setting the start ...
    masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.LastRecord = masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord               ' ... and end points to the active record
    masterDoc.MailMerge.Execute False                                        ' run the MailMerge based on the above settings (i.e. for one record)
    Set singleDoc = ActiveDocument                                           ' Identify the ActiveDocument (foremost doc after running the MailMerge) as "singleDoc"
    singleDoc.SaveAs2 _
        FileName:=masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("DocFolderPath").Value & Application.PathSeparator & _
            masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("DocFileName").Value & ".docx", _
        FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument                                      ' Save "singleDoc" as a word docx with the details provided in the DocFolderPath and DocFileName fields in the MailMerge data
    singleDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        OutputFileName:=masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("PdfFolderPath").Value & Application.PathSeparator & _
            masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("PdfFileName").Value & ".pdf", _
        ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF                                      ' Export "singleDoc" as a PDF with the details provided in the PdfFolderPath and PdfFileName fields in the MailMerge data
    singleDoc.Close False                                                    ' Close "singleDoc", the variable "singleDoc" can now be used for the next record when created
    If masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord >= lastRecordNum Then     ' test if we have just created a document for the last record
        lastRecordNum = 0                                                    ' if so we set lastRecordNum to zero to indicate that the loop should end
    Else
        masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdNextRecord           ' otherwise go to the next active record
    End If

Loop                                                                         ' loop back to the Do start
```

End Sub                                                                          ' Mark the end of the Subroutine

when I debug, I get this part of the code highlighted.

singleDoc.SaveAs2 _
FileName:=masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("DocFolderPath").Value & Application.PathSeparator & _
masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("DocFileName").Value & ".docx", _
FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument                                      ' Save "singleDoc" as a word docx with the details provided in the DocFolderPath and DocFileName fields in the MailMerge data
singleDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat _

I've tried updating the first line above to SaveAs _  and it still doesn't work past the first letter.

Comment: See *Send Mailmerge Output to Individual Files* in the **Mailmerge Tips and Tricks** page at:
https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html